# ms-access: is it possible to save an access form separately from DB?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i have a front end access with a bunch of forms and reports. i want to be able to save one of the forms by itself to its own file. how do i do it?

Comment: What exactly is your real goal here? That is, why do you think saving this form to its own file is going to be useful?

Comment: @david: i would like to be able to have it as a backup

Comment: A backup of what? The form design? Why not just keep a copy of the whole database? Why does it need to be a separate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the undocumented SaveAsText method to save your form as a plain text file.

```
Application.SaveAsText acForm, "frmLinks", CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "frmLinks.txt"
```

You can use SaveAsText for other object types, too.  Perhaps you would also be interested in saving acReport object types?

Comment: And Application.LoadFromText can import it back (since this is a backup).